# AsyncTask finalizar execução

Tags: android, async

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia pausar, cancelar essa função assim que eu fechar a Activity que está executando.

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: A AsyncTask você pode cancelar a qualquer momento, basta chamar o método cancel(boolean). É muito importante entender que a task não é cancelada imediatamente e o ideal é você sempre que possível verificar dentro da execução se a task foi cancelada usando o método: isCancelled()

Como você comenta sobre pausar ou cancelar ao sair da Activity o ideal é tratar dentro do método onPause() caso voce queira parar assim que perde o foco.

Answer (score 1):

Confesso com certa vergonha que nunca tentei isso nas minhas aplicações, apesar de ser uma funcionalidade que pode ser considerada básica (interromper uma requisição HTTP), mas creio o seguinte código irá funcionar quando for chamada `task.cancel()`:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView bmImage;
    private InputStream in = null;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conexao = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openConnection();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   while (in == null && false == isCancelled()) {
                       // Aguarda conexão ser estabelecida e InputStream estar disponível
                   }

                   if (isCancelled()) {
                       conexao.disconnect();
                   }
                }
            }).start();
            in = conexao.getInputStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

A solução ainda não está completa porque falta interromper a leitura do `InputStream` em caso de chamada de `task.cancel()` (embora seja possível que acabe funcionando assim mesmo caso o `disconnect()` leve o `InputStream` sendo lido a lançar uma `IOException`), mas não estou com tempo no momento para pensar em uma solução.